# Функция WmiSetBrightness не работает, когда вызывается через wmic

Tags: wmi

Я пытаюсь установить яркость дисплея моего ноутбука с помощью `wmic` следующим образом:

```
wmic /namespace:\\Root\wmi CLASS WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods CALL WmiSetBrightness(50,0)
```

В результате получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR:
Description = Value out of range
```

В справке показано следующее:

```
Call                    [ In/Out ]Params&type                   Status
====                    =====================                   ======
WmiSetBrightness        [IN ]Brightness(uint8)                  Implemented

                        [IN ]Timeout(uint32)
```

Как правильно установить яркость?

Comment: Здесь принято разговаривать по русски.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов ТС пока не выразил желания о переводе. Зачем вы решате за него? Если он пожалает перемещения на enSO, что тогда?

Comment: А как можно перенести вопрос на enSO?

Comment: @0xdb во первых он принял новую редакцию и согласился с переводом :), и во вторых у меня была в свое время подобная проблема, но я на ее "плюнул", поэтому мне кажется уместным этот вопрос на форуме. Это не первый случай, когда я вижу хорошие вопросы на английском, которые, ИМХО, интересны. Я также помню случаи, когда в ответ на просьбу перевести с английского авторы просто удаляли хорошие вопросы.

Comment: Я даже и не знал что вопросы можно переносить между разделами SO

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Первого достаточно, я не посмотрел,  кто принял правку.

Comment: Давайте тогда вопрос удалим, я его чуть позже на английской ветке размещу.

Comment: @TeoLan Уже нельзя перенести, вопрос переведён. Проста задайте там новый. Почему вы хочете его удалить, вы же приняли правку?

Comment: Я неправильно понял предложение Александра, думал что правка создаст комментарий на русском, а английская версия тела вопроса останется. Оказалось, что на русский переводится само тело вопроса. Насколько я знаю, дублирование вопросов не приветствуется на SO, поэтому этот вопрос лучше удалить.

Comment: Не надо удалять. Поставил плюс вопросу. Вы вполне можете задать вопрос и на en.so, и на ru.so (а также на португальском и японском) - это не запрещается, а даже приветствуется.

Comment: Любопытно. Пробовал по-разному, но не хочет работать. Получилось сделать вот так в powershell: `(gwmi -Namespace Root\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(0,50)`

Comment: У меня вчера тоже так получилось), но хочу выяснить, можно ли одной командой.